# Loading very large graph into gremlin server via BulkLoaderVertexProgram

Tags: gremlin-server

I'm trying to load a very large dataset split into several csv files (over 20GB in size) into gremlin server. I'd read that the most efficient way to load the dataset into gremlin server is via BulkLoaderVertexProgram.

Can someone kindly please show a short java code sample of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`BulkLoaderVertexProgram` was [deprecated some time ago](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.8/upgrade/#_bulk_import_and_export) as TinkerPop no longer tries to generalize the concept of bulk loading for graphs. Most of the graph providers out there have their own bulk loading utilities which are remarkably different in their approach and functionality which makes a common interface to all of them difficult to accomplish while still supporting their full capabilities. I'd recommend that you look at the bulk loading options specific to your graph and see what options work well there for you.